# Berenstein-Fomin-Zelevinsky's Ininital seeds and initial seeds from Postnikov diagrams

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, cluster-algebras

In [Cluster algebra III](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0305434.pdf) by Berenstein-Fomin-Zelevinsky, Theorem 2.10, for any pair of reduced words $(u,v)$, they constructed an initial seed for the cluster algebra $\mathbb{C}[B^{u,v}]$, where $B^{u,v}$ is a double Bruhat cell.

On the other hand, in Grassmannian case (correspond to type A case), from any Postnikov diagram, in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0311148) by Scott, an initial seed is constructed.

In Grassmannian case, what are the relations between the initial seeds constructed by Berenstein-Fomin-Zelevinsky and the initial seed from Postnikov diagrams? Thank you very much.

Comment: The most direct relationship is between the Grassmannian and its big Schubert cell, where the coordinate rings are related by looking at a degree 0 subalgebra of a certain (small) localisation of the Grassmannian. This translates into removing a frozen variable from the initial quiver of the Grassmannian seed, but the actual variables change in a much more complicated way. Apologies for the slightly bad form in saying this, but you might find some of my papers on this with Launois helpful, and/or contact me by email if you like. (If you prefer, just ignore the word "quantum" in those papers.)

Comment: @Jan Grabowski, thank you very much!